# When setting up MySQL on a VirtualBox VM, can I connect to it from the host computer?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, mysql

I have VirtualBox running Ubuntu on my Windows 7 computer.

Is it possible for me to connect to the MySQL server running on the VM from my Windows 7 host?

Answer (score 3):

You can enable NAT on the virtual machine so that it's IP address is available on windows.

Another option is to enable port forwarding on the "Guest" machine, so that it is accessible on the "Host" machine as 127.0.0.1, this way you can just connect to localhost:3306.

I would suggest not doing option #2 if you are into having mysql on both your host and the guest.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the virtual machine its own IP address - check out :

http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Advanced_Networking_Linux

> The virtual machine may be fully integrated into the network and you may have access between all virtual machine and the host if you do a little bit more.
>
> A bridge can contain only one physical/virtual device. So you can create your bridge as follow:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> # set PATH for the case we are called via sudo or su root
>
> PATH=/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
>
> # create a tap
> tunctl -t tap1 -u <user>
> ip link set up dev tap1
> f
> # create the bridge
> brctl addbr br0
> brctl addif br0 tap1
>
> # set the IP address and routing
> ip link set up dev br0
> ip addr add 10.1.1.1/24 dev br0
> ip route add 10.1.1.0/24 dev br0
> ```
>
> With this code you will be able to contact the virtual machine
> attached to the Host Interface tap1 from the host and the host from
> the virtual machine. The IP adress should not conflict with the main
> IP address of your PC which will probably been within the range
> 192.168.0.0/16.